# Switching TS to target ES2015, getting unexplained errors named exports

Tags: typescript

I have been happily transpiling a Typescript library of mine to CJS for some time but decided I wanted to transpile to ES2015 to get more out tree-shaking. Anyway, I suddenly got a number of errors that I'd not seen before. Many of them were both understandable and helpful but I'm left with a few cases of an error I just can't comprehend. Here's an example:

> error TS4043: Return type of public getter 'db' from exported class has or is using private name 'RealTimeDB'.

In this case the code that's being complained about looks like this:

```
public get db() {
  return this._db;
}
```

and indeed the TYPE of `_db` is:

```
private _db: RealTimeDB;
```

My assumption here is that it implying that the type `RealTimeDB` is private. It is not; it is publicly exported. Not only does the module it is taken from exposing it but I have also exposed it directly in this package too. Am I misunderstanding the error?

> error TS4041: Return type of public getter 'relationships' from exported class has or is using name 'ISchemaRelationshipMetaProperties' from external module "/Users/xxx/mine/forest-fire/firemodel/src/decorators/schema" but cannot be named.

In this case it gets even more odd as not only is `ISchemaRelationshipMetaProperties` exported but it is exported as PART of this project (note: this is the "firemodel" project). Here are a few code snippets to further demonstrate this:

```
public get relationships() {
  return this._schema.META.relationships;
}
```

and the `_schema` property:

```
protected _schema: T;
```

Where T extends `BaseSchema` which states:

```
public META?: Partial<ISchemaOptions>;
```

And then `ISchemaOptions` includes:

```
relationships?: ISchemaRelationshipMetaProperties[];
```

And this can be found locally as:

```
export interface ISchemaRelationshipMetaProperties extends ISchemaMetaProperties {
  isRelationship: true;
  isProperty: false;
  relType: ISchemaRelationshipType;
}
```

Sorry this chain is a bit long but the point is all of the dependencies are local to the package not *external* as the error suggests. They are also ALL exported as part of the package.

---

Complete source can be found here:

[List Class](https://github.com/forest-fire/firemodel/blob/29ba1693a0abda1b4bab3a84dcd8f911863e911c/src/list.ts) which throws the first error

---

## Update

I have found a way to get rid of the errors but I still have no idea WHY I get the errors. In this example from above where I was getting an error about the 'RealTimeDB' using a private name ... I simply change to:

```
protected get db(): RealTimeDB {
  return this._model.db;
}
```

Note that the only change is I'm explicitly stating the return type in the getter and explicitly stating what it implicitly already knew. This is the same pattern I've used in all other errors and with the same result. I guess I'm ok now but I'd really love to hear from someone about WHY this is happening. It *feels* like a bug in TypeScript.

Answer (score 0):

> It is not; it is publicly exported.

Must also be exported from the file that is showing this error. Add:

```
export {RealTimeDB}
```

## More

- you are currently only *importing* it into the file.

Comment: I had already added `export { RealTimeDB } from "abstracted-firebase";` to the file which is throwing the error. Error is still thrown. If you looked up the repo you're not seeing this because I haven't pushed these changes yet. I can if it's helpful.